# Why am I being blocked from asking questions?

Tags: support

I tried posting a question just now, and this is what I got:

**It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon! 
You've asked 4 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.**

I have in fact posted 4 (four) questions here, and their scores are +6, +3, +1, and -1.

Exactly how can this be interpreted as "some of which have not been received very well by the community"?

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions? Unfortunately, they can contribute to a question block.

Comment: Answer e.g. on [meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) The exact wording seems to vary across meta sites.